# Theme a custom menu with theme_menu_tree()

Tags: drupal, menu, themes, drupal-7

I'm trying to override a custom menu output in a block so that instead of

```
    <ul class="menu">...</ul>
```

I can get

```
    <select name="menu title">...</select>
```

In Drupal 6, I could use function `theme_menu_tree($tree,$menu_name="") {...}` but this doesn't work in Drupal 7 with function `theme_menu_tree($variables) {...}`.

I've tried `theme_menu_tree__mymenu($variables) {...}` with no success.  How do I specify a unique menu in Drupal 7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem with overriding and correct naming of the theme_menu_tree function for a specific menu name. What I found I suppose that the correct name of your function should be: `YOUR_THEMENAME_menu_tree__YOUR_MENUNAME`

The name of your menu could be taken from Administration » Structure » Menus pages. It seems to me that Drupal adds word "menu" before all of the new user menus.
In my case I created a menu called "Testing menu" in a theme "Mytheme" and the name of the overriding function was: `mytheme_menu_tree__menu_testing_menu`