# YOUR_THEMENAME_menu_tree__YOUR_MENUNAME not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-navigation

I have a custom Menu called "Footer", the machine readable name is "menu-footer".
And I want override the theme_menu_tree() function for the menu. My theme name is "abc", so I tried abc_menu_tree__menu_footer() and it is not working. But modifying abc_menu_tree() is working, so it must have to do with the overriding of custom menus.

I checked this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774398/theme-a-custom-menu-with-theme-menu-tree) but it doesn't work.
Is there anything I need to do in order to allow overriding for custom menus?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Edit:

The code of the function:

```
function abc_menu_tree__menu_footer($variables) {
  return '<nav class="sub-navigation"><ul>' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul></nav>';
}
```

abc_menu_link__menu_footer() can't be overridden too. In abc_menu_link() you are able to check context, so this is not a big problem. If I check if the theme of the element is "menu_link__menu_footer" it is working for the menu links.

Edit2:

I can't override abc_menu_tree for the main menu too. abc_menu_tree__main_menu is not working.

Comment: Strange because this same function works for me for 4 custom menu in template.php in same format. Can you please post the whole function here ?

Comment: Have you flushed the site cache after declaring the new function inside theme's `template.php` file ?!

Comment: I flushed the caches in the performance settings and added the code and additional infos to my question.
Thanks for your replies! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use THEME_menu_tree on the primary menu, instead of using THEME_menu_tree__main_menu(), you will need to use THEME_menu_tree__primary()

This is because the menu that provides the primary links is defined in admin/structure/menu/settings.

I thought of this while digging around in the radix theme's radix_preprocess_page() function, wherein the main menu variable is set up for use in the page.tpl.php by using variable_get(). Duh!  It's so easy to forget about those tiny little configurations.

So yeah.  THEME_menu_tree__primary() and THEME_menu_tree__secondary() are probably the functions you are looking for!